# How to Remove Stenographic Image Injections in Python

Tags: security, web, code-injection, websecurity

## Backstory

So, I am developing a web server in Flask using Python. I have a bit of a background in Cyber Security and I know for a fact that php and other payloads can be stored in images. My Web Application is basically based on the user uploading PDF files, images and other data so I can perform OCR on them, my question is this that if someone hides a payload in an image using `https://github.com/chinarulezzz/pixload`, then how can I detect it and remove it.

## How to Programmatically Defend Web Apps from These Attacks

I know that this is kind of a no-go question on stack overflow, but I am looking for Library or in general some sort of reference on how to better protect my application programmatically against this type of attack.

Comment: As you said, this is off-topic here. Try [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: Yes, you can put a payload inside an image file, but that payload is useless there unless there is a separate vulnerability in your web app that allows execution of that payload. So make sure your web app doesn't have any such vulnerabilities, and don't worry about a dormant payload hidden in images.